# Update columns with different values depending upon different condition of rows from scd2 type table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE table0(
id int,
atr0 varchar(max),
primary key(id));

CREATE TABLE table1(
id int,
atr0 varchar(max),
begin_date datetime,
end_date datetime);
```

The second table(table1) is SCD2 type ,attribute `id` can be not unique. "Current" rows have `end_date = '9999-12-31'`. There are 2 cases:

- there are 2 same id in table1 - first with end_date = whatever time(<'9999-12-31'),when this row finish their valid, second with `end_date = '9999-12-31'`.
- Second case is when there is only one `id` where `end_date != '9999-12-31'`.

Need to:

```
UPDATE table0
SET atr0 = table1.atr0
FROM table1
```

If there is row with `end_date = '9999-12-31'`, then update `atr0` from this row.

Else (if there is only 1 row with `end_date != '9999-12-31'`) assign `atr0` null value.

Looks easy - first should update second case rows, next first case rows where `end_date = '9999-12-31'`

```
update a
set a.atr0 = b.atr0
from table0 a inner join(
select * 
from table1 tbl1
where not exists(select id, max(end_date) 
                 from table1 c
                 where c.id = tbl1.id
                 group by id 
                 having max(end_date)= '9999-12-31')) b
            on a.id = b.id;
```

Nevertheless, i need to combine 2 updates into 1 update
tell me plz - is it posible in MS SQL Server?

Example:

`table0`:

```
 id |  atr0
----+--------
  0 | value0
  1 | value0
```

`table1`

```
 id |  atr0  | begin_date |  end_date
----+--------+------------+------------
  0 | value0 | 2017-01-01 | 2018-08-30
  0 | value1 | 2018-08-30 | 9999-12-31
  1 | value1 | 2018-08-30 | 2018-08-30
```

Desired results: `table0`, after update:

```
 id |  atr0
----+--------
  0 | value1
  1 |  NULL
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question, as it still seems vague to me.  It seems you want to update table0 joining to table1 on id and get the value of atro from table1 where the end_date is the max(end_date) for that id.  If the row with the max(end_date) for that id = '9999-12-31', then you want the value of atr0 from that row otherwise you want null.  Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @ScottHodgin right, you understad it rigth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this solution works for you.

```
--demo setup
Declare @TABLE0 TABLE(id int,atr0 varchar(max));
DECLARE @TABLE1 TABLE(id int,atr0 varchar(max),begin_date datetime,end_date datetime);

INSERT INTO @TABLE0(id,atr0) VALUES(0,'VALUE0'),(1,'VALUE0')
INSERT INTO @TABLE1(ID,atr0,begin_date,end_date) VALUES
(0, 'Value0', '2017-01-01', '2018-08-30'),
(0, 'Value1', '2018-08-30', '9999-12-31'),
(1, 'value1', '2018-08-30', '2018-08-30')


--The solution
UPDATE T0
SET T0.atr0 = CASE 
        WHEN T1.end_date = '9999-12-31'
            THEN t1.atr0
        ELSE NULL
        END
FROM @TABLE0 T0
JOIN @TABLE1 T1
    ON T1.id = T0.ID
        AND T1.end_date = (
            SELECT MAX(end_date)
            FROM @TABLE1
            WHERE ID = T1.ID
            )

SELECT *
FROM @TABLE0
```

---

```
| id | atr0   |
|----|--------|
| 0  | Value1 |
| 1  | NULL   |
```